# How to find a slice from n: m of singular value decomposition matrix, whithout cicles

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, svd

SVD is equal to UΣVT, where U - m * k matrix,Σ - k * k diagonal matrix, VT - transposed k * m matrix. Also UΣVT can be determined as A = u1σ1vT1 + u2σ2vT2 + u3σ3vT3 where u1 - first column of U, σ1 - first element of Σ, vT1 - first column of V.
Scipy contains function svd(a), which returns UΣVT.
How to find for example a = u2σ2vT2 + u3σ3vT3 without cycles.

Comment: please provide an example of input and the expected output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The reconstruction can be performed by matrix multiplication

```py
U, s, VT = la.svd(A)
np.allclose((U * s) @ VT, A)
np.allclose(U @ np.diag(s) @ VT, A)
```

If you find the second singular value as `s[1]` and the thrid as `s[2]`, if you give an arbitrary set of indices, you can reconstruct the sum as

```py
(U[:,indices] * s[indices]) @ VT[indices,:]
```

Take for example the matrix

```py
A = np.diag(np.arange(5))
```

```txt
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 4.]])
```

The sum you mentioned is calculated as

```py
(U[:,2-1:3] * s[2-1:3]) @ VT[2-1:3,:]
```

```txt
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```